# Xamarin Cross-platform PCL GetStringAsync error

Tags: c#, xamarin, async-await

I am currently learning how to develop cross-platform app 
I came across a bug , I don't know if it's bug or not 
but when i try to use the function `GetStringAsync` as showing in below image 
it cause an error anyone could help please ?

here is the code

```
protected override async void OnAppearing()
{
    var client = new HttpClient();
    string a =await client.GetStringAsync("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts");

    base.OnAppearing();
}
```

for the PCL Project I have added through Nuget Microsoft.Net.Http
and for Android project I have added `System.Net.Http`

I just realize that if you want to download Microsoft.Net.Http
in your android project you need to download Microsoft.bcl.Build
first , I did that BTW and still the problem persist.

Comment: You didn't include an code or error messages in your post, how are we possibly supposed to help you?  And please do NOT post them as images.

Answer (score 1):

`async void` is allowed on event handlers. However `OnAppearing` is not an event handler. It is a virtual method on the base class of the page. The good thing though is that the `OnAppearing` method is actually called before the `Appearing` event.

So subscribe to the `Appearing` event of the page/view in the OnAppearing method.

```
protected override void OnAppearing() {
    this.Appearing += Page_Appearing;
}
```

and call your async code on an actual even handler which is called after.

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
private async void Page_Appearing(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    //...call async code here
    var url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts";
    var a = await client.GetStringAsync(url);

    //unsubscribing from the event
    this.Appearing -= Page_Appearing;
}
```